# How can I get pygame for Python3?

Tags: 11.10, python

There is a package (python-pygame) for Python2 available from the universe repository.  However, I want to work through the tutorial in the [Invent with Python book](http://inventwithpython.com/chapter17.html).  Going through SPM (Synaptic), I cannot find a pygame resource for Python3.

Also, I looked on the [Pygame](http://pygame.org/news.html) website and it is not clear if Pygame is available for Python3 (though the book indicates that it is).

Can someone help me with my dilemma?

Comment: `IMPORTANT_MOVED.txt` seems... important. So I changed the `svn...` line to `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`

Comment: Try [this answer on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10227363/1103747).  It worked perfectly for me (minus the part where I forgot to copy and paste the apt-get command with the dependencies and had to hunt down and install them __by hand__).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

```
Thanks to Sergey's suggestion, this is how to get it working:
INSTALL
(1) Move to a directory where you want the source code to be downloaded to
(2) svn co svn://seul.org/svn/pygame/trunk pygame
    NOTE:  Be sure to use the svn method.  Simply downloading the pygame*.tar.gz
           file from the pygame downloads page didn't work!
(3) cd pygame
(4) python3 config.py
    NOTE:  This confirms that you have the dependencies.
(5) python3 setup.py build
(6) sudo python3 setup.py install
    NOTE:  On my machine, I have the distro's python3.2 installed (which is in
           the /usr/lib directory).  This step places the pygame module into
           /usr/local/lib -- which is what you want (per Sergey's suggestion).

TEST
(1) python3
(2) At the '>>>' prompt, type "import pygame"
    VALIDATION:  If you get another '>>>' prompt, all is well.
```

> per BlaXpirit, you may also choose to use hg instead of svn:
>
> `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`

Answer (score 6):

From [Pygame wiki](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Does%20Pygame%20work%20with%20Python%203?):

> **Does Pygame work with Python 3?**
>
> Yes. Pygame 1.9.2 supports Python 3.2 and up. Only the orphaned _movie module (not built by default) does not.

However, there seems no pre-packaged Pygame packages for Python 3 in Ubuntu repositories, at least as of 14.04.

I would suggest you to get the source packages from the pygame website and install it locally into a virtualenv or buildout. Globally installing python modules in evil anyway :) Here are the instructions: http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu

Alternatively you can try this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/pygame

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I have posted the steps in the original question for an explicit answer.

Comment: @TheGeeko61: I think you should post that as an answer, it's not "bad" in any way.

Comment: Alright, I'm doing so...

Comment: No longer up to date

Comment: @JonathanLeaders: It wasn't THAT much out of date: there are still no pre-compiled packages and you still have to install from source. I've added a few links to the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Someone needs to make a `python3-pygame` package that does this, but no one has yet

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial python3-dev python3-numpy libav-tools \
    libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsmpeg-dev \
    libsdl1.2-dev  libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
cd pygame
python3 setup.py build
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: On 18.04 I had to replace libav-tools with ffmpeg but that did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the below command to install pygame for Python3.

```
pip3 install pygame
```

It could install pygame correctly on Ubuntu 16.04 and Python Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again to everyone.

Just did a clean install of Mint 18 Cinnamon 64bit, and was following TheGeek61's post above to get Pygame working again.

But when I tried `python3 setup.py build` came up with an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 109, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

After some searching, ran the following:

> sudo pip install -U setuptools

Which then allowed Pygame for Python3 to install successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The pre-requisite packages right now on the Mavproxy wiki will not work with Raspbian :

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev python3-opencv python3-wxgtk3.0 python3-pip python3-matplotlib python3-pygame python3-lxml python3-yaml`

Instead you will need to use the old one :

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python-opencv python-wxgtk3.0 python-pip python-matplotlib python-pygame python-lxml python-yaml
```