# Installing pygame for python3.2

Tags: python

I am installing pygame for Python3.2 because I want to do all the examples shown in a book, but on Ubuntu 12.04 I only have pygame for python version 2.7. But that is not as good as I want it. So I started to do it like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97717/how-can-i-get-pygame-for-python3)

But, when starting this command:

```
python3.2 config.py
```

there were this output:

```
PORTMIDI: not found
PORTTIME: not found
AVFORMAT: not found
SWSCALE : not found
```

What should I do, so I can install pygame without any problems ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some Pygame dependencies are missing.

I'd suggest installing these packages:

- libportmidi-dev - library for real-time MIDI input/output
- libportmidi0 - library for real-time MIDI input/output
- libavformat-dev - development files for libavformat
- libavformat52 - ffmpeg file format library
- libswscale-dev - development files for libswscale
- libswscale0 - ffmpeg video scaling library

  sudo apt-get install libportmidi-dev libportmidi0 libavformat-dev libavformat52 libswscale-dev libswscale0