# How do I install Pygame in virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

In installed `python-virtualenv`, because [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97717/how-can-i-get-pygame-for-python3) said I should use virtualenv to install pygame. However, I'm not really sure how that's accomplished.

What I did (following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279959/how-to-create-a-virtualenv-with-python3-3)):

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3 --no-pip
```

And then I don't know where to go.

How do I install pygame to be used in the virtualenv?

**Edit:** I followed GuySoft's instructions, and everything installed great. However, when I tried `import pygame` in python3, I got the following error:

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alden/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: /home/alden/.virtualenvs/pywork3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pygame/base.cpython-33m.so: undefined symbol: PyCObject_Check
```

Comment: `src/pygame.h:75:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory` You probably need the Python development files.

Comment: Yeah, right at the beginning of the log I failed to notice that it warned about missing dependencies (including python3.3-dev), so I found the list on the pygame wiki and am installing them right now.

Comment: @Timo I installed all the [recommended dependencies](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu#Python_3.x), but I'm still missing the jpeg dependency. Do you know what this would be?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you have pip in your virualenv, its useful.

Note: **must** have pygame's dependencies installed, you can find out what they are and install them with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
```

Then try this:

```
rm -rf ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3 #clean what you have there
mkdir -p ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3
virtualenv --no-site-packages --distribute -p /usr/bin/python3.3 ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3
. ~/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/activate
pip install pygame
```

Comment: Just added an important step, tested and this should work :)

Comment: After I added the Source code repository, everything installed just fine; however, I ran into another error when I tried to import pygame, which I've added to the OP.

Comment: That's a different issue. Pygame on python 3 is experiential. [Try following these instructions](https://plus.google.com/115566537842716428333/posts/HFQeyiKh3tZ) (aka download from source the latest version, and confirm you indeed have all the requirements).

Comment: Ok, will check that out. I also contacted the writer of the book to ask him about it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work any more. pygame isn't in the python packages repositroy.

Comment: @BenDavis It is according to [Ubuntu package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/python-pygame). Do you have universe repository enabled?

Comment: @GuySoft, that's the ubuntu package. It's not in the python package index (PyPI).

Answer (score 1):

that is working for me without problem:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
```

than:

```
pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

Comment: Sad to report that this has ceased to work in ubuntu 15.10.  The pip install just hangs. Attempting to download and install using "pip -e" shows missing libraries, which may be causing pip to fail silently.

Comment: I've been forced to to the usual "python ./setup.py install", then copy the results to my virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that pygame will not install in a virtualenv on ubuntu 15.10.

The problem is missing links to libswscale and libavformat.

On my system I added the following symlinks:

```
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libswscale /usr/include/libswscale
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/libavformat /usr/include/libavformat
```

At that point I was able to follow the [http://pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu#Installing pygame with pip](http://pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu#Installing%20pygame%20with%20pip) instructions. I am now levitating in a ball of clear light.

Answer (score 0):

For pygame 2 (using SDL 2) with Python 3 on Ubuntu, you need to install the following dependencies (according to [CompileUbuntu at pygame.org](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu)):

```
sudo apt-get install --yes libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libfreetype6-dev python3-setuptools python3-dev python3 libportmidi-dev
```

Then use pip to install `pygame` in your `venv`:

```
pip install pygame
```

A complete script could look like this:

```
$PYTHON_VENV_DIR=.venv

sudo apt-get install --yes python3-venv

# all these are required for pygame-2
sudo apt-get install --yes libsdl2-dev libsdl2-image-dev libsdl2-mixer-dev libsdl2-ttf-dev libfreetype6-dev python3-setuptools python3-dev python3 libportmidi-dev

python3 -m venv $PYTHON_VENV_DIR

source $PYTHON_VENV_DIR/bin/activate

python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip3 install wheel
pip3 install pygame
```