# How to install pygame?

Tags: 13.10, python

I am running Ubuntu 13.10. I have python 2.7.5 with anaconda 1.8.0. Whenever I start python and type `import pygame` it tells me that there is no module named pygame.

How can I install pygame?

Comment: Did you try using `sudo apt-get install python-pygame`?

Comment: yes,i did try it

Comment: Were any of the answers helpful?

Comment: yeah,I did not look at the version no. properly.I typed in 13.04 but it was actually 12.04.I upgraded it and it worked!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The reason you are not able to import pygame into your python interpreter is because you are installing it for python2 and starting the python3 interpreter(Ubuntu 13.10 uses python3 by default).

To install pygame for python2(your version is 2.7.5), do this on a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

and then start the python2 interpreter

```
python2
```

and then try to import pygame as

```
import pygame
```

To set python2 as **your** default interpreter, you can set an alias in your bash_aliases file. To do this, open a terminal and type:

```
nano ~/.bash_aliases
```

This may open an empty file, depending upon whether you have set an alias before and then type

```
alias python='python2'
```

Do not change symlinks in `/usr/bin/python3`, since this may break many application in Ubuntu 13.10 which use python3 vociriferously.

Comment: I use python with anaconda 1.8.0.So whenever I start python,it starts with anaconda

Comment: got it thanks everyone and special thanks to you Jobin.

Comment: @saisanjeev: Either accept the answer as it helped you(if it did), else please post the answer that helped you and mark as accepted.

Comment: Note, to install pygame in python3 you have to build it from the source code. Following the simple instructions here (http://askubuntu.com/a/406410/327339), plus installing the one extra dependency before building (see my comment below the answer), worked for me in Xubuntu 16.04 LTS with Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 4):

This should install pygame for python 3, as python3-pip is required for pygame.

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-dev  
 sudo pip3 install pygame
```

Comment: python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user

Answer (score 3):

#### Install Pygame for Python 3

To install PyGame for Python 3.x on Ubuntu 19.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pygame
```

To install python3-pygame in Ubuntu 18.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line to sources.list.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-proposed universe # for 19.04 replace cosmic with disco
```

Save sources.list with the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Update the list of available software and install python3-pygame.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python3-pygame
```

#### Install Pygame for Python 2

To install python-pygame in 20.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python-pygame
```

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm Jobin's suggestion in his comment:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
```

Works flawlessly. Tested on 13.10.

Next time if you want to install a python package you can search whether it is in the repositories by running:

```
apt-cache search pygame
```

Then you can see the packages (if they are in the repositories) and their names. The output for `apt-cache search pygame` is

```
lightyears - single player real-time strategy game with steampunk sci-fi
psychopy - environment for creating psychology stimuli in Python
pyntor - flexible and componentized presentation program
python-pygame - SDL bindings for games development in Python
python-pyglet - cross-platform windowing and multimedia library
python-soya - high level 3D engine for Python
python-soya-dbg - high level 3D engine for Python - debug extension
python-soya-doc - high level 3D engine for Python
solarwolf - Collect the boxes and don't become mad
```

In this list you can select the package (here: `python-pygame`) and run `sudo apt-get install the-package-name`.

For more debugging of dependencies see [Installing pygame with pip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312767/installing-pygame-with-pip?rq=1).

Comment: yeah,it's the same thing i get.But,when i type 'python' in the Terminator or terminal,I get this:-'Python 2.7.6 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (32-bit)| (default, Nov 11 2013, 10:47:19) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.'Then after the 3 arrows, I typed :'import pygame' and it showed this error:-'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pygame'.Why is this so?Maybe because i use anaconda python?

Comment: I don't see why that would be the problem. Are you typing `'import pygame'` or `import pygame` (without the '')?

Comment: I am typing just 'import pygame'

Comment: I feel its because i have anaconda 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

If you have done all the steps above and still are getting the ModuleNotFoundError then you might be using some version of Python that does not support/or was not installed Pygame into.

Try typing, `python2.7` or `python3.6` or a terminal.
If you are using the Thonny IDE go under:

- Tools
- Manage Thonny plug-ins
- Search for Pygame in the search bar then double click the pthird-party plugin.