# "import pygame" is not working

Tags: software-installation, games, python3

I'm just trying to build some Python game, but `import pygame` is not working.

I got this error massage:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/dinushi/g.py/snackgame.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dinushi/g.py/snackgame.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pygame?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/399824/how-to-install-pygame)

Comment: Thank you, I install pygame but still my code dose not work, same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the **pygame** module (no need to use sudo):

```
pip3 install --user pygame
```

Another way to install is by `sudo apt-get install python3-pygame`

Comment: Command 'pip3' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python3-pip, Thank you I installing it,

Comment: Sorry about that; shouldn't have assumed that you had pip3 installed. I added another way to install the module globally.

Comment: I install It using sudo command, but my code still get this error, I use pycharm and python3

Comment: What exactly did you install? I see where you installed pip3 - what did you do next?

Comment: I install it using this code,   sudo apt-get install python-pygame

Comment: That's the python 2.x version. My answer has the install command for the 3.x version.

Comment: Thank you It's work