# `pip install pygame` produces `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vD9diA/pygame/`

Tags: 18.04, python, raspberrypi, pip, python-2.7

### What I'm running on

- OS: **Ubuntu Server 18.04.4**
- Computer: **Raspberry Pi 4 Model B**
- pip version (the default installed on 18.04.4 LTS): **pip 9.0.1**
- python version (the default installed on 18.04.4 LTS): **python 2.7**

### My issue

I'm trying to run `pip install pygame`, as per [this documentation](https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/motorized-focus-camera/). I was getting an error along the lines of `Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-vD9diA/pygame/`, as well as some information about config files not being found. I ran these commands to resolve the missing config file problems:

```
% sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev
% sudo apt install libsdl1.2-dev
% sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev
% sudo apt install python-mysqldb
```

and I'm now getting the following error when running `pip install pygame`:

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...


    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 1.2.15
    FONT    : not found
    IMAGE   : not found
    MIXER   : not found
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : not found
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    PORTTIME: not found
    FREETYPE: found 21.0.15
    Missing dependencies

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-e36J9A/pygame/
```

### What I've tried that hasn't worked

1. `pip install --upgrade setuptools`: output didn't change
2. `pip install --upgrade pip`: breaks pip, had to invoke `python -m pip uninstall pip` to undo. Here was the output of `pip install pygame` before I uninstalled:

   > WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
   >   Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
   >   To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
   >   DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. pip 21.0 will drop support for Python 2.7 in January 2021. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
   >   Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
   >   Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (1.9.1release)
3. `sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame` as recommended by https://askubuntu.com/a/312779/1065820 : produces this output:

   > Reading package lists... Done
   >   E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
4. `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` and `sudo apt-get install python-dev`: both are already at newest version, so no change

---

At this point, I've looked at dozens of help pages and am running out of ideas. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten it mostly working now, so I'll leave this here for the next weary traveller.

The following command made it executable:

```
% sudo apt-get install git python-dev python-numpy python-opengl \
    libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsmpeg-dev \
    libsdl1.2-dev libportmidi-dev libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev \
    libtiff5-dev libx11-6 libx11-dev fluid-soundfont-gm timgm6mb-soundfont \
    xfonts-base xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-cyrillic fontconfig fonts-freefont-ttf \
    libfreetype6-dev
```

To test it, I used:

```
% git clone https://github.com/pygame/pygame.git
% sudo apt install libsdl2-config #to resolve missing dependencies error I got from `python setup.py build` inside ~/pygame
% python -m pygame.tests
```

pygame.tests only sort of worked, but at this point I've switched to Raspbian and moved on so I'm not gonna wrestle with it further. Here's the lengthy output of pygame.tests:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
skipping pygame.tests.cdrom_test (tag 'interactive')
skipping pygame.tests.midi_test (tag 'interactive')
skipping pygame.tests.touch_test (tag 'SDL1_ignore')
loading pygame.tests.base_test
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                      ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
  ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
            ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                      ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
  ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
            ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                      ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
  ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
            ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                      ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
  ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
            ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                      ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
  ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
            ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
loading pygame.tests.blit_test
loading pygame.tests.bufferproxy_test
loading pygame.tests.camera_test
loading pygame.tests.color_test
loading pygame.tests.compat_test
loading pygame.tests.constants_test
loading pygame.tests.cursors_test
loading pygame.tests.display_test
loading pygame.tests.draw_test
loading pygame.tests.fastevent_test
loading pygame.tests.font_test
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                      ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
  ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
            ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
loading pygame.tests.ftfont_test
loading pygame.tests.image__save_gl_surface_test
loading pygame.tests.image_test
                               loading pygame.tests.imageext_test
                                                                 loading pygame.tests.joystick_test
                                                                                                   loading pygame.tests.key_test
          ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                                   ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
            ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                                   ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                          ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
                      ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
loading pygame.tests.mask_test
loading pygame.tests.math_test
loading pygame.tests.mixer_music_test
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
loading pygame.tests.mixer_test
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
loading pygame.tests.mouse_test
loading pygame.tests.overlay_test
loading pygame.tests.pixelarray_test
loading pygame.tests.pixelcopy_test
loading pygame.tests.rect_test
loading pygame.tests.rwobject_test
loading pygame.tests.scrap_test
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                      ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
  ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
            ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
loading pygame.tests.surfarray_test
ALSA lib confmisc.c:767:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
                                                      ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
  ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
                                                                                                                ALSA lib confmisc.c:1246:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
                                                         ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
                                                ALSA lib conf.c:5007:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
            ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
loading pygame.tests.surflock_test
loading pygame.tests.sysfont_test
loading pygame.tests.threads_test
loading pygame.tests.time_test
loading pygame.tests.transform_test
loading pygame.tests.version_test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/tests/__main__.py", line 131, in <module>
    run_and_exit(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/tests/test_utils/run_tests.py", line 340, in run_and_exit
    total, fails = run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/tests/test_utils/run_tests.py", line 300, in run
    'total: %d != untrusty_total: %d' % (total, untrusty_total))
AssertionError: Something went wrong in the Test Machinery:
total: 974 != untrusty_total: 979
```