# Install pygame on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, python

After following the instructions [How do I install Pygame in virtualenv?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299950/how-do-i-install-pygame-in-virtualenv/299965#299965), running `pip install pygame' now returns:

```
Downloading/unpacking pygame
Running setup.py egg_info for package pygame
Skipping module _numericsurfarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)
[GCC 4.6.3] build.
Skipping module _numericsndarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)
[GCC 4.6.3] build.
Skipping module scrap for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)
[GCC 4.6.3] build.
Skipping module _camera for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)
[GCC 4.6.3] build.

warning: no files found matching 'readme.txt'
no previously-included directories found matching '*/CVS'
no previously-included directories found matching '*/*/CVS'
Installing collected packages: pygame
Running setup.py install for pygame
Skipping module _numericsurfarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)
[GCC 4.6.3] build.
Skipping module _numericsndarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)
[GCC 4.6.3] build.
Skipping module scrap for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)
[GCC 4.6.3] build.
Skipping module _camera for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)
[GCC 4.6.3] build.
building 'pygame.imageext' extension
gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/src/imageext.o
In file included from src/imageext.c:47:0:
src/pygame.h:75:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /home/david/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python3.2 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/david/.virtualenvs/pywork3/build/pygame/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-0tu3l3-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/david/.virtualenvs/pywork3/include/site/python3.2:
Skipping module _numericsurfarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)

[GCC 4.6.3] build.

Skipping module _numericsndarray for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)

[GCC 4.6.3] build.

Skipping module scrap for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)

[GCC 4.6.3] build.

Skipping module _camera for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)

[GCC 4.6.3] build.

running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'pygame.imageext' extension

gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -D_REENTRANT -I/usr/X11R6/include -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include/SDL -I/usr/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.2mu -c src/imageext.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/src/imageext.o

In file included from src/imageext.c:47:0:

src/pygame.h:75:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /home/david/.virtualenvs/pywork3/bin/python3.2 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/david/.virtualenvs/pywork3/build/pygame/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-0tu3l3-record/install-record.txt --install-headers /home/david/.virtualenvs/pywork3/include/site/python3.2 failed with error code 1 in /home/david/.virtualenvs/pywork3/build/pygame
Storing complete log in /home/david/.pip/pip.log
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

Indicates to me that you haven't installed the Python development (headers) package. For Python 2.7 (the default), this is included in [python-dev [image: Install python-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-dev), for the Python 3.2 version you seem to be using this is [python3.2-dev [image: Install python3.2-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python3.2-dev). Note that this will only work if you installed Python 3.2 from the Ubuntu packages.

After installation, try again to install the Python package.

---

The [new error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312973/install-pygame-on-12-04/312977?noredirect=1#comment395391_312977) you're getting,

> ```
> error: could not create '/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pygame': Permission denied`
> ```

could be because of two reasons:

- You're not working in a Python virtualenv. Without working in a virtualenv, it will try to install in the system folders (`/usr/local/` etc.). Solution: switch to the virtualenv properly, e.g. `workon <virtualenvname>` and run the `pip` commands in the same terminal window.

  **OR**, if you don't intend to work with virtualenvs:
- You're trying to install it system-wide, but you didn't elevate your privileges to do so. Solution: prepend the `pip` command with `sudo`, e.g.

  ```
  sudo pip install pygame
  ```

Comment: New error: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5801725/

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson See my updated question. Do you know what a virtualenv is? If not, see the reason at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much. I do plan on using a virtualenv, (I'm learning about them as part of this process). How do I install `python-dev` from within the virtuaenv? `sudo apt-get install python-dev` after activating says it is already installed.

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson Read up on virtualenvs. The Python interpreter is usually shared with the global system one, so there's no need to install specific headers inside the paths of the virtualenv. Just install Python and the development package once, globally (Ubuntu apt-get packages). The Python packages (pip/easy_install) should go in the virtualenv.

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson Also, if this answer is helpful and solved your issue, consider accepting it. Thanks.

Comment: @gervdijk Inside of the virtualenv, `pip install pygame` returns: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5801962/. `sudo pip install pygame` outside of the virtualenv seems to install fine.

Comment: @DavidY.Stephenson That output shows you're running Python 2.7 this time instead of 3.2! This is not the same virtualenv as you've showed earlier. If you created a new virtualenv, you didn't use the same interpreter as the one you've created the question for. For 3.2 it skips the camera module: `Skipping module _camera for Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:11:55)` (from your question) - that's where the error happens now. For 2.7 see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5898792/1254292

Comment: @gervdijk I generally use python 3.2, but the tutorial I'm using wants 2. Thank you so much for all your help!